# What is the alternative the function waitForNextUpdate (@testing-library/react-hooks) in @testing-library/react for async hooks?

Tags: reactjs, testing, react-hooks, react-testing-library, react-testing

I want to test my custom hook but in React 18 @testing-library/react-hooks library is not working, instead I am using @testing-library/react it has renderHook function and it works fine, but this library does not have waitForNextUpdate function for asynchronous hooks. For this reason, I can't test my custom async hooks.

Answer (score 18):

An alternative could be replacing it by `waitFor`.

Before:

```
await waitForNextUpdate();
expect(fetch).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
```

After

```
await waitFor(() => {
   expect(fetch).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It only worked for me when I used `act` and `waitFor`:

```js
await act(async () => {
  await waitFor(() => {
    expect(result.current.isAuthenticated).toBeUndefined();
  });
});
```